# How to know Growth of Database in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I view the database size information history?

I want data like

[Check Monthly Growth of Database in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6158/how-to-check-monthly-growth-of-database-in-sql-server/)

But the data displayed is backup size. Can I know the history of database size from rows data and logs in the previous months / years? As in [size] in [sys]. [database_files]

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL Script to Show Database Growth Based on Backup Sizes
Change the 'XXXX' to your database name prior to running. With this information, you can give a pretty good idea to your customer about an average data growth, month by month for the past X months.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
but what I want is database size from rows data and logs, not backup sizes.